# Comparison and $i++ in a while

Tags: php, while-loop, comparison

I have a while loop `while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {$i++ }`

And then I want to do something like:

```
if ($i == 5 && the total number of items is more than 10) {do this}
```

In other words, if the increment goes to 10+ then $i == 5 should do something else do nothing

Comment: what do you mean  with 'get that total number from $i++' ??   i++ is a incremental for $i  .. is just  a shortcut for $i  = $i+1;   so your question is not clear   . could be you are looking for the number of rows fetched ??

Comment: I want to say if the increment goes to 10+ then do this else do nothing. In other words if I have more than 10 items in that list then I want $i==5 to be true else it do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

```
if ($i == 5 && $result->num_rows > 10){do this}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PHP mysqli_result::fetch_all](https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) to achieve this.

```
$rows = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)
$i = 0;
foreach($rows as $key => $row) {
  $i++;
  if($i === 5 && count($rows) > 10) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

I'm not sure but `$key` should be a "normal" array index starting at 0. If so you could use `$key === 5` instead of `$i`.